# Is there any way to get Swype on my Moto Droid?

Tags: google-play-store, motorola-droid, swype

Is there anyway to get Swype from outside the Market? Its not available there, and I see its already running on Droid X, so I was thinking it'd probably work on Droid as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

http://www.droid-life.com/2010/03/08/swype-beta-apk-file-for-those-who-missed-it/

There is a download link, and step-by-step instructions for installing the beta.

Comment: That works, but its just a trial and its expired.

Comment: That beta version expired months ago

Answer (score 2):

Swype has just released a second beta, but I believe this is only for those who were on the beta before.

Nevertheless, you can try it here: http://beta.swype.com/

To install Swype, you install the "Swype installer" which will authenticate you as a valid user and then download and install the actual Swype APK. They are keeping tight control over the actual Swype APK.

Comment: As of Feb 20, '11 there is a beta available at the URL Sam Pride mentions; I just installed it on my Droid and it works fine.   Now for the learning curve...

Answer (score 0):

There is no lawful way - you can download an apk of the production version on the internet but this is piracy and so unlawful and the beta has expired. You either need to have it preinstalled on your phone (like with the samsung galaxy s) or buy it from their site (which I can't see how to do - it is not on the market, at least not for my htc desire).

There are many other free swype alternatives on the market but I can't remember them off the top of my head.

Comment: It's on the market for me on a Galaxy S4, but it may not be compatible with all devices  yet. SwiftKey has a 'flow' feature ala swype and Google Keyboard has it too (and is free) so they may be alternatives. I loved Swype but SwiftKey (after a few weeks of learning) is the only one I use these days. It was 2 Euro on sale, well worth it. Maybe try Google keyboard first!